# jquery clone drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i have following scenario of drop down list

[image]

Whenever i select cat1 options, sub cat 1 options will be populated. But if i add another category 
it should only add cat1 options not along with sub cat options.But in my case both of cat 1 and sub cat options are loaded. Following are my code to clone drop down list.

```
        <div class="new-categories">
                    <div class="new-category">
                        <select class="category-select" name="categories">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="1">cat 1</option>

                    </select>
                    <select class='category-select-sub' style="display:none">
                        <!-- loaded from ajax -->
                    </select>
        </div></div>
    <a href="#" class="add-another-cat smallest" style="">Add another category</a>


$('.add-another-cat').click(function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             var $orDiv = $('.new-category:last').after($('.new-category:first').clone());

});
```

This is how i actually supposed to look like

[image]

Thanks.

update: populate ajax result

```
 $('div.new-categories').on('change', 'select.category-select', function () { 
             var $newselect = $('<select />').addClass('category-select-sub');
    $(this).parent().append($newselect);
            var cat_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url:baseUrl+'categories/getsubcat',
                data:{'id':cat_id},
                dataType:'json',
                async:false,
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    var subhtml = data;
                    $('.category-select-sub').show();
                    $('.category-select-sub').html(subhtml);
                }
            });
        });
```

Once new cat list has been added and an option is selected, the first sub cat are changing according to new list. How to prevent this?

Comment: You should retain a clean state `new-category` and clone it automatically when the page is loaded. Then clone it again when the `add-another-cat` is pressed. This way you won't clone a modified `new-category`.

Comment: Why not empty the category-select-sub after the clone?

Comment: Your second question is very easy, you use `$(".category-select-sub")` instead of keeping a reference to the select-sub you create and refer to it. writing `$(".category-select-sub")` affects all .category-select-sub. you should simply write `$newselect.show().html(subhtml);`

Comment: edited my answer to include solution for the category-select-sub issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense to me, but this is what I think you are trying to do. Correct me if I am wrong.

"I would like to clone the div `new-category` and append it to the div `new-categories`. I only want the first select list cloned, not anything else.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZp5M/

```
$('a.add-another-cat').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //clone the first div
    var $newdiv = $('div.new-category:first').clone();
    //remove the second select (if there is one)
    $newdiv.children('select.category-select-sub').remove();
    //append new div
    $('div.new-categories').append($newdiv);
});
```

Comment: ok. but how to prevent when i select an options on first category-select it should populate list on first sub cat list not the rest of others..?

Comment: @SaraswathiApavoo - that's really a different question. I don't know how you populate your second select list. You should ask a new SO question if you need help with that.

Comment: you stuff works well, now once i add new cat and i select option for it, the first sub cat also are changing according to result of new cat list

Comment: If it cloned an event handler, you'll need to unbind that from the newly cloned element:  `$(yourNewElement).unbind('change');`  (or whichever event is used).

Comment: also your  jsfiddle.net/HZp5M/1  not works well. Just notice that it append more than once..

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SCArr

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div id="clone" class="new-category" style="display:none;">
    <select class="category-select" name="categories">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">cat 1</option>

    </select>
    <select class='category-select-sub' style="display:none">
        <!-- loaded from ajax -->
    </select>
</div>
<div class="new-categories">
</div>
<a href="#" class="add-another-cat smallest" style="">Add another category</a>

<script>
$('.add-another-cat').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $orDiv = $('.new-category:last').after($('#clone').clone().removeAttr('id').show());
});
$('.new-categories').html($('#clone').clone().removeAttr('id').show());
</script>
```

Comment: ok. but how to prevent when i select an options on first category-select it should populate list on first sub cat list not the rest of others..?

Comment: You need to use `id` on the `<select class='category-select-sub'>` instead of having `class` only. Let's say when `<select id="category-select-1" class="category-select" name="categories">` is selected, `<select id="category-select-sub-1" class='category-select-sub'>` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see how you have the second sub select menu as it might affect the solution.

### Solution 1 - better creation with an empty state

the problem is in your HTML structure

```
<div class="new-category">
      <select class="category-select"> ... </select> 
      <select> ... </select> 
</div>
```

When you clone `.new-categories` you clone both select elements. 
You need to reconstruct your HTML so you will clone only what you want. 
There will be something you will need to create by yourself without a clone. 
For example, something like this:

```
$('.new-category:last').after( $("<div/>")
         .addClass("new-category").append($('.category-select:last').clone()).append($("<select/>").addClass(".category-select-sub").hide());
```

### Solution 2 - empty the sub select after clone

[a jsfiddle that shows how to empty a select](http://jsfiddle.net/MM9Fc/4/)

### What to do about auto-populating the sub select affecting all?

This is easy, your code explicitly refer to all sub selects. see the you code saying

```
$('.category-select-sub').show().html(subhtml);
```

This code means - set this HTML to all ".category-select-sub" elements. But you want only a specific element with this class - not all..

You should only refer to the sub select you created - which is easy as you already have a reference to it - so the success function should have something like this :

```
$newselect.show().html(subhtml);
```

Comment: By creating a new element you will have removed the event handler which autopopulates the submenu. You will need to add the event back. By leveraging `clone` you can avoid that step.

Comment: I did not see anything about an event handler which autopopulates the submenu. however - you should take a look on "on" or "live" to resolve this as you need event handlers to elements that do not exist yet.

Comment: please add details about autopopulating submenu requirements so I will be able to supply code snippet for it as well.

Comment: It's actually not my question. I was just commenting on your solution. He says that the second submenu is populated via ajax, which means that the intial selection item must have an event on it.

Comment: ok - live will still resolve this. but maybe a better solution would be to empty the second selection in that case..